# How to convert dictionary to default dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

```
mapfile = {
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
}

_buf = {}
for x in (x for x in mapfile.keys() if 0==x%4):
    try:
        s = "0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(mapfile[x+3], mapfile[x+2],
                                                    mapfile[x+1], mapfile[x+0])
        print "offset ", x, " value ", s
        _buf[x] = int(s, 16)
    except KeyError as e:
        print "bad key ", e

    print "_buf is ", _buf
```

Since I am using dictionary, I am getting `KeyError`. Plan is to make dictionary as `defaultdict(int)` so that in default dictionary it will pad zero when there is `KeyError`. But I didn't find any solution. How I can convert dictionary to default dictionary?

Answer (score 22):

You can convert a dictionary to a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> a = {1:0, 2:1, 3:0}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> defaultdict(int,a)
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0})
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of re-creating the dictionary, you can use `get(key, default)`. `key` is the key that you want to retrieve and `default` is the value to be returned if the key isn't in the dictionary:

```
my_dict = { }
print my_dict.get('non_existent_key', 0)
>> 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I think, `KeyError` can be solved here by setting `0` as default value.

```
In [5]: mydict = {1:4}

In [6]: mydict.get(1, 0)
Out[6]: 4

In [7]: mydict.get(2, 0)
Out[7]: 0
```

Hope this helps. You can change your code to something like `mapfile.get([x+3], 0)`.

OR

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = {1:4}
mydefaultdict = defaultdict(int, mydict)
>>>mydefaultdict[1]
4
>>>mydefaultdict[2]
0
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate for my requirement, I have to add in catch block?

Comment: If key does not exist, what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks . Key missing is random, not only for (mapfile.get([x+3], 0) . I want something like if any key is missing pad "Zero to that"

Comment: _buf = defaultdict(int,mapFile)

for x in (x for x in mapFile.keys() if 0==x%4):
  #  try:
        s = "0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}{3:02x}".format(mapFile[x+3],mapFile [x+2],mapFile[x+1],mapFile[x+0])
        print "offset ", x, " value ", s
        _buf[x] = int(s, 16)
   # except KeyError as e:
      #  _buf.get('non_existent_key', 0)

print "_buf is ", _buf                                                                               KeyError: 1879048215

Comment: So you can change as `mapfile = defaultdict(int, mapfile)` above the forloops.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could convert the dictionary to a `defaultdict` simply by:

```
mapfile = collections.defaultdict(int, mapfile)
```

In your example code it might be better just make it part of the creation process:

```
mapfile = collections.defaultdict(int, {
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
})

print(mapfile[1879048205])  # -> 0
print(mapfile['bogus'])  # -> 0
```

Yet another alternative would be to derive your own class. It wouldn't require much additional code to implement a dictionary-like class that not only supplied values for missing keys like `defaultdict`s do, but also did a little sanity-checking on them. Here's an example of what I mean — a `dict`-like class that only accepts missing keys if they're some sort of integer, rather than just about anything like a regular `defaultdict`:

```
import numbers

class MyDefaultIntDict(dict):
    default_value = 0
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, numbers.Integral):
            raise KeyError('{!r} is an invalid key'.format(key))
        self[key] = self.default_value
        return self.default_value

mapfile = MyDefaultIntDict({
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
})

print(mapfile[1879048205])  # -> 0
print(mapfile['bogus'])  # -> KeyError: "'bogus' is an invalid key"
```

Comment: Thanks Martineau.                              mapfile = MyDefaultIntDict({
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
})
How can I replace this by single line, since I have to do this, cause I ve huge data . Is this right approach ? mapfile = MyDefaultIntDict(mapfile)

Comment: Yes, `mapfile = MyDefaultIntDict(mapfile)` would be fine if `mapfile` is initially a regular `dict`.

Comment: Thanks Martin.useful answer +1

Comment: Also wanted to point out it's possible add whatever kind validity-checking to the `__missing__()` method makes sense, like even when the key is an integral value, you might want to make sure it's within a certain range of values. Other possibilities would be to also accept strings when they represent valid integers, like `"1879048203"` or `"0x7000000B"` do.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, user wants to convert the below dictionary to a default-dictionary:

```
mapfile = {
    1879048192: 0,
    1879048193: 0,
    1879048194: 0,
    1879048195: 0,
    1879048196: 4,
    1879048197: 3,
    1879048198: 2,
    1879048199: 17,
    1879048200: 0,
    1879048201: 1,
    1879048202: 0,
    1879048203: 0,
    1879048204: 4,
    # intentionally missing byte
    1879048206: 2,
    1879048207: 1,
    1879048208: 0 # single byte cannot make up a dword
}
```

API for `defaultdict`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

The `defaultdict` constructor requires two arguments here. A default factory function as the first parameter and the plain dictionary itself. The purpose of the factory function is to return a default value when the dictionary is accessed with an unknown key, without throwing any `KeyError`.

If we observed the original question, it requires a `defaultdict` of `int`, with an assumption that the `default` value for an unknown key is `0` below code should work as fine:

```
defaultdict(lambda: 0, mapfile)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.